Google Sheets Conditional Formatting using AND
I am trying to conditionally format the top 10 scores in a list and the following formula works perfectly:
=$G2>=LARGE($G$2:$G,10)
However, I have two different school classes in my list of data and I would like the top 10 highlighted from each class. I have tried using AND in the formula but I can't quite get the formatting right.
Please help
Formatting Test


2 conditional formatting rules added to your test sheet Column_H
Apply to range: H2:H
=let(Σ,"Y82324_CommStuds",and($C2=Σ,$H2>=large(index(if($C:$C=Σ,$H:$H)),10)))


So I was sort of there with the logic.... let and sigma mean what though? Just so I can understand for the future.

In simpler terms instead of repeating the term "Y82324_CommStuds" two times; I am assigning it to a variable Σ to use it in later stages. look into let()
